# How to break SQL script execution

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, error-handling

I am working on sql script and I am having a requirement of stop continuing the script if some conditions are not satisfied.

When I Google it, I found the RaisError with 20 severity level will terminate it.
But for some reasons I cannot use that option.

Can please provide me what are the possible alternatives to stop SQL script execution.

Comment: Why is raising a error unacceptable? Also is this script a stored procedure?

Comment: I did not clearly understand your fist question. For second question; no this is not a SP

Comment: What is the script? Does it comprise multiple batches? [Have you seen the answers here?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/659188/73226)

Answer (score 10):

From the [RAISERROR documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) (emphasis mine):

> Severity levels from 0 through 18 can be specified by any user. **Severity levels from 19 through 25 can only be specified by members of the sysadmin fixed server role or users with ALTER TRACE permissions.** For severity levels from 19 through 25, the WITH LOG option is required.

It's highly likely the principal you're executing the script as does not meet these criteria.

There's nothing wrong with using `RAISERROR`; you're just using a severity level that's excessive. I use level 16 as a default for an error that is raised and the sequence will be terminated. If you want to be more accurate, you can follow the levels given by Microsoft itself:

[image]

Now, having said all that, depending on the context of the script, using `RAISERROR` may not be enough, as it doesn't "exit" the script by itself (using normal severity levels).

For example:

```
RAISERROR(N'Test', 16, 1);

SELECT 1;   /* Executed! */
```

This will *both* raise an error *and* return a result set.

To terminate the script immediately, I prefer to use [`RETURN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) (using `GOTO`-type constructs are generally discouraged in most programming circles where alternatives exist):

```
RAISERROR(N'Test', 16, 1);
RETURN;

SELECT 1;   /* Not executed */
```

Or handle the error using [`TRY/CATCH`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976%28v=sql.90%29.aspx), which will cause execution to jump to the `CATCH` block if the severity is 11 or higher:

```
BEGIN TRY
    RAISERROR(N'Test', 16, 1);
    SELECT 1;   /* Not executed */
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT 2;   /* Executed */
END CATCH

BEGIN TRY
    RAISERROR(N'Test', 10, 1);
    SELECT 1;   /* Executed */
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT 2;   /* Not executed */
END CATCH
```

A separate problem is if the script spans multiple batches -- `RETURN` will only exit the *batch*:

```
RAISERROR(N'Test', 16, 1);
RETURN;

SELECT 1;   /* Not executed */
GO

SELECT 2;   /* Executed! */
```

To fix this, you can check [`@@ERROR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188790%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) at the start of every batch:

```
RAISERROR(N'Test', 16, 1);
RETURN;

SELECT 1;   /* Not executed */
GO

IF (@@ERROR != 0)
    RETURN;

SELECT 2;   /* Not executed */
```

Edit: As Martin Smith correctly points out in the comments, this only works for 2 batches. To extend to 3 or more batches, you can cascade raising errors like so (note: the `GOTO` method does not solve this problem as the target label must be defined within the batch):

```
RAISERROR(N'Test', 16, 1);
RETURN;

SELECT 1;   /* Not executed */
GO

IF (@@ERROR != 0)
BEGIN
    RAISERROR(N'Error already raised. See previous errors.', 16, 1);
    RETURN;
END

SELECT 2;   /* Not executed */
GO

IF (@@ERROR != 0)
BEGIN
    RAISERROR(N'Error already raised. See previous errors.', 16, 1);
    RETURN;
END

SELECT 3;   /* Not executed */
```

Or, as he also points out, you can use the [`SQLCMD` method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2590364) if that's appropriate for your environment.

Comment: That last suggestion doesn't work. [See pastebin](http://pastebin.com/4cP6ieB7). I like the [sqlcmd method here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2590364/73226)

Answer (score 8):

You can utilize the [`GOTO`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180188.aspx) statement to skip around wherever you want.  In other words, you run into an error or some other condition, and you can have a label at the bottom of the script (i.e. `TheEndOfTheScript:`) and just issue a `goto TheEndOfTheScript;` statement.

Here is a quick sample:

```
print 'here is the first statement...';

print 'here is the second statement...';

-- substitute whatever conditional flow determining factor
-- you'd like here. I have chosen a dummy statement that will
-- always return true
--
if (1 = 1)
    goto TheEndOfTheScript;

print 'here is the third statement...';

print 'here is the fourth statement...';


TheEndOfTheScript:
print 'here is the end of the script...';
```

The output of this execution will be the following:

```
here is the first statement...
here is the second statement...
here is the end of the script...
```

As you can see, the `GOTO` has skipped printing the third and fourth statements and jumped right to the label (`TheEndOfTheScript`).

Comment: Only works when there is a single batch, will break as soon as you've a GO statement.

Comment: My stored procedures tend to finish with something like; GOTO terminate; failure: RAISERROR(N'Error.', 16, 1); terminate: -- this means that I can throw in "BEGIN RAISERROR(N'I don''t like this!', 16, 1); GOTO failure; END" further up the program to branch to the end, and exit with a RAISERROR error, as well as any error messages caused by SQL statements.  Finishing on RAISERROR(), as explained in other examples, means that whatever happens next can read from ##ERROR, as long as that is done first, e.g. SET #returnerror = ##ERROR; IF ( #returnerror <> 0 ) GOTO failure (can't' type @ so used #)

Answer (score 7):

The best way is to use SET NOEXEC ON

You can read more here: [How to STOP or ABORT or BREAK the execution of the statements in the current batch and in the subsequent batches separated by GO Statement based on some condition in SQL SERVER](http://sqlhints.com/2015/05/23/how-to-stop-or-abort-or-break-the-execution-of-the-statements-in-the-current-batch-and-in-the-subsequent-batches-separated-by-go-statement-based-on-some-condition-in-sql-server/)

Comment: Very nice article.

Comment: `SET NOEXEC ON` provides the greatest flexibility and lowest overhead for the many different scenarios that can arise.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the `SET NOEXEC ON/OFF`, however in Stored Procs (containing a single block)  I simply use `RETURN` statement.

Caveats:
In a script file, if you have multiple `GO` statements, the `RETURN` will only come out of the current block and continue with the next block/batch.

Note: `GOTO` is supposed to be a bad coding practice, use of "`TRY..CATCH`" is recommended, as it was introduced since SQL Server 2008, followed by `THROW` in 2012.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not in the correct server, then I don't want to run my scripts.

this works for me:

```
BEGIN TRAN T1
SELECT @@TRANCOUNT


IF 'xxx-V-SQL-xxx\xxx_DEVELOPMENT' <> @@ServerName  
   begin 
      RAISERROR ( 'Wrong Server!!!',1,1) WITH NOWAIT 
      if @@trancount > 0
         rollback;

      SELECT [the_transaction_count before return]=@@TRANCOUNT
      RETURN
   end;

select [was this executed]='Yes'

SELECT [the_transaction_count]=@@TRANCOUNT

if @@trancount > 0
   ROLLBACK
SELECT [the_transaction_count]=@@TRANCOUNT
```

but sometimes when I cannot use return, [then this one works:](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/191467/22336)

```
SET NOEXEC OFF;
BEGIN TRAN T1
SELECT @@TRANCOUNT


IF 'xxx-V-SQL-xxx\xxx_DEVELOPMENT' <> @@ServerName  
   begin 
      RAISERROR ( 'Wrong Server!!!',1,1) WITH NOWAIT 
      if @@trancount > 0
         rollback;

      SELECT [the_transaction_count before return]=@@TRANCOUNT
      SET NOEXEC ON;

   end;

select [was this executed]='Yes'

SELECT [the_transaction_count]=@@TRANCOUNT

if @@trancount > 0
   ROLLBACK
SELECT [the_transaction_count]=@@TRANCOUNT
```